# Oracle SQL CASE WHEN ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, case-when

Getting error

`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

When i run the following query

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE when t.cancelled = 'TRUE' then '0' 
else t.amount END AMOUNT,
FROM table t
```

If i run it with either a number or text for the else output, like this, it works.

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE when t.cancelled = 'TRUE' then '0' 
else 'xxx' END AMOUNT,
FROM table t
```

Comment: Is t.amount a NUMBER?

Comment: In that case convert it to a char type. (ie: `SELECT ... else TO_CHAR(t_amount) ...`)

Comment: ...or use `then 0 else`

Comment: For other people brought here by google: in my case, it was a problem with a bind variable.

So, check those, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `0` instead of `'0'`. Amount is a number, and numbers aren't quoted.

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE when t.cancelled = 'TRUE' then 0 
else t.amount END AMOUNT,
FROM table t
```

Comment: @Matt, your query has 0 has '0' that is varchar, i placed it as 0

Comment: Good explanation. I just went ahead to explain further in layman words as an answer, hope you won't mind. I have mentioned the attribution :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB, i see you quite active on oracle forums good work :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @RADAR,

The reason for the error is that `t.amount` field is a `NUMBER` data type and not a `string`.

Your `CASE`  expression is internally trying to fit a `STRING` in a `NUMBER` data type.

As already suggested in RADAR's answer, use zero as a number and NOT as a string.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for this problem from here [ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER while adding 1 to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803977)

As the answer stated :

> Blockquote
> It seems Oracle requires for CASE structures the type of all THEN expressions to be consistent with the TYPE of the expression after the first THEN.
> No type conversions are performed.

This is short and reason of the error. Basically, The data type of the value you mention after first THEN part has to be same in all following THENs of the same level.

Comment: good catch! because to_char will not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

try using `to_number(t.amount)`

```
SELECT distinct 
CASE when t.cancelled = 'TRUE' then 0 
else to_number(t.amount) END AMOUNT,
FROM table t
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't convert my string value to number, so I converted the number to string using [TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) function.