# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER while adding 1 to a date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Probably a silly mistake, but I couldn't figure this out myself. When I run this query in Oracle 11g.

If this question is answered in SO, please let me know the link.

```
with LAST_BUSINESS_DAY as (select DECODE(to_char(last_day(to_date('29-mar-2013')), 'D'), 
                                  , '7', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , '1', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , to_char(last_day('29-apr-2013'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as LAST_BD from dual),
      HOLIDAYS as (select distinct rpt_day
                     from rpt_days rpt left join
                          calendars cal on rpt.calendar_id = cal.calendar_id
                    where rpt.type = 2 
                      and cal.group = 4)
  select case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
              then LAST_BD
              else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D')
                          , '6', LAST_BD
                          , '2', LAST_BD
                          , LAST_BD)
         end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
    from LAST_BUSINESS_DAY LBD 
         inner join HOLIDAYS H on LBD.LAST_BD = H.rpt_day
```

I get the result as

```
LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
===================
29-MAR-2013
```

Now, when I try to add a day to the `LAST_BD` date, it throws an error.

```
with LAST_BUSINESS_DAY as (select DECODE(to_char(last_day(to_date('29-mar-2013')), 'D'), 
                                  , '7', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , '1', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , to_char(last_day('29-apr-2013'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as LAST_BD from dual),
      HOLIDAYS as (select distinct rpt_day
                     from rpt_days rpt left join
                          calendars cal on rpt.calendar_id = cal.calendar_id
                    where rpt.type = 2 
                      and cal.group = 4)
  select case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
              then LAST_BD
              else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D') -- line 35
                          , '6', LAST_BD - 1 -- CHANGED THIS
                          , '2', LAST_BD + 1 -- CHANGED THIS
                          , LAST_BD)
         end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
    from LAST_BUSINESS_DAY LBD 
         inner join HOLIDAYS H on LBD.LAST_BD = H.rpt_day
```

**Error Message**

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 35 Column: 20

As I said, this might be a simple overlook from my side. I tried converting the `LAST_BD` to a `date`, but didn't work.

I tried changing the `DECODE` as below

```
case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
     then LAST_BD
     else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D')
                 , '6', to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1
                 , '2', LAST_BD + 1 -- line 37
                 , LAST_BD)
end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
```

and got this error :

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 37 Column: 42

So, I changed the  `line 37` to this,

```
case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
     then LAST_BD
     else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D')
                , '6', to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1
                , '2', to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1
                , LAST_BD)
end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
```

and this time its a different message.

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 35 Column: 20

Any help to get this corrected is greatly appreciated.

**ANSWER** :

```
with LAST_BUSINESS_DAY as (select DECODE(to_char(last_day(to_date('29-mar-2013')), 'D'), 
                                  , '7', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , '1', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , to_char(last_day('29-apr-2013'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as LAST_BD from dual),
      HOLIDAYS as (select distinct rpt_day
                     from rpt_days rpt left join
                          calendars cal on rpt.calendar_id = cal.calendar_id
                    where rpt.type = 2 
                      and cal.group = 4)
  select case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
              then LAST_BD
              else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D')
                          , '6', to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                          , '2', to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                          , LAST_BD)
         end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
    from LAST_BUSINESS_DAY LBD 
         inner join HOLIDAYS H on LBD.LAST_BD = H.rpt_day
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So do I see it right, that you converted `LAST_BD`from `VARCHAR2` to `DATE` (due to):

```
to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

In the second query you try to subtract `1` from this `VARCHAR2`:

```
LAST_BD - 1
```

This won't work. As a consequence you get the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

What would probably work is, if you convert it to `DATE`, add `1` and convert it back to `VARCHAR2`

```
with LAST_BUSINESS_DAY as (select DECODE(to_char(last_day(to_date('29-mar-2013')), 'D'), 
                                  , '7', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , '1', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , to_char(last_day('29-apr-2013'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as LAST_BD from dual),
      HOLIDAYS as (select distinct rpt_day
                     from rpt_days rpt left join
                          calendars cal on rpt.calendar_id = cal.calendar_id
                    where rpt.type = 2 
                      and cal.group = 4)
  select case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
              then LAST_BD
              else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D') -- line 35
                     , '6', to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
                     , '2', to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY') 
                          , LAST_BD)
         end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
    from LAST_BUSINESS_DAY LBD 
         inner join HOLIDAYS H on LBD.LAST_BD = H.rpt_day
```

Note that the conversion back to `VARCHAR2` is required, because `DECODE` allows only values of one type.

Comment: thanks...this works. Just to mention it is `to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, not `to_char (to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that DECODE expects a CHAR argument of some kind and `LAST_BD + 1` and even the `TO_DATE(LAST_BD...` return a NUMBER and a DATE respectively.

The following SQL Fiddle demonstrate how to fix this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8ac4a3/9

Here is the query:

```
with LAST_BUSINESS_DAY as (select DECODE(to_char(last_day(to_date('29-mar-2013')), 'D')
                                  , '7', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 1), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , '1', to_char((last_day('29-mar-2013') - 2), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                                  , to_char(last_day('29-apr-2013'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')) as LAST_BD from dual),
      HOLIDAYS as (select distinct reporting_day
                     from tbm_reporting_days trdy left join
                          tbm_calendars tcal on trdy.calendar_id = tcal.calendar_id
                    where trdy.type = 2 
                      and tcal.site_id = 4)
  select case when to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'D') is null
              then LAST_BD
              else DECODE(to_char(to_date(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') , 'D')
                          , '6', TO_CHAR(
                              (TO_DATE(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1), 'D')
                          , '2', TO_CHAR(
                              (TO_DATE(LAST_BD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') - 1), 'D')
                          , LAST_BD)
         end as LAST_BD_OF_MONTH
    from LAST_BUSINESS_DAY LBD 
         inner join HOLIDAYS H on LBD.LAST_BD = H.reporting_day
```

You have to convert the number or date back to a CHAR with TO_CHAR.

Comment: But I need the date, not the day ordinal

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Understood, I was just helping you understand the error is all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Oracle requires for **case** structures the type of all **then** expressions to be consistent with the type of the expression after the first **then**.
No type conversions are performed.

Comment: This is the short and to the point explanation and reason of the error. 

Basically, The data type of the value you mention after first THEN part has to be same in all following THENs of the same level.

Thanks user2038893  . Saved my day.