# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle

I am trying to pass user input in Python into SQL to filter data by date range. I had no trouble doing it in SQL like:

```
SELECT * from trades
WHERE share_id = 1
AND broker_id =1
AND transaction_time >= TO_DATE('2020-11-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
AND transaction_time <= TO_DATE('2020-12-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I also had no trouble in Python with only the transaction_time part like:

```
from_date_val = input("Enter from-date (YYYY-MM-DD) to search, enter nothing to skip: ")
to_date_val = input("Enter to-date (YYYY-MM-DD) to search, enter nothing to skip: ")

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM trades WHERE 1=1
                  AND transaction_time >= CASE WHEN :from_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END
                  AND transaction_time <= CASE WHEN :to_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:to_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END""", 
                  from_date = from_date_val, 
                  to_date = to_date_val)
```

But if I do:

```
share_id_val = input("Enter share id to search, enter nothing to skip: ")
broker_id_val = input("Enter broker id to search, enter nothing to skip: ")
from_date_val = input("Enter from-date (YYYY-MM-DD) to search, enter nothing to skip: ")
to_date_val = input("Enter to-date (YYYY-MM-DD) to search, enter nothing to skip: ")

cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM trades WHERE 1=1
                  AND share_id = CASE WHEN :share_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN :share_id ELSE share_id END
                  AND broker_id = CASE WHEN :broker_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN :broker_id ELSE broker_id END
                  AND transaction_time >= CASE WHEN :from_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END
                  AND transaction_time <= CASE WHEN :to_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:to_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END""", 
                  share_id = share_id_val, 
                  broker_id = broker_id_val,
                  from_date = from_date_val, 
                  to_date = to_date_val)
```

It returns: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER.

On the lines of `from_date = from_date_val` and `to_date = to_date_val`.

It's literally driving me nuts for a few hours, could anyone please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `from_date = from_date_val` and `to_date = to_date_val`? Have you tried using `TO_NUMBER` on `:share_id` and `:broker_id`? Or converting those python values from a string to an int before you pass them to the bind variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL CASE WHEN ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER 00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678672/oracle-sql-case-when-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-char-got-number). The problem is in your `CASE` statement with `share_id` or `broker_id`, obviously. Because it appeared after addition of them.

Comment: Thank you @MT0 it worked!! The error message kept on telling me it's the prob of the date, I've never thought there might be problems with those ids.

Comment: Thank you @astentx it worked!! The error message kept on telling me it's the prob of the date, I've never thought there might be problems with those ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`share_id` and `broker_id` are `NUMBER` data types; however, in Python, the `input` function returns a string and you are passing that directly as a bind variable and then:

```sql
CASE WHEN :share_id IS NOT NULL THEN :share_id ELSE share_id END
```

The `:share_id` bind variable would be a string data type and the `share_id` column has a `NUMBER` data type; which results in your error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER.
```

To fix it you need to convert the string input values to numbers. You can do the conversion using `int()` in Python:

```py
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM trades WHERE 1=1
                  AND share_id = CASE WHEN :share_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN :share_id ELSE share_id END
                  AND broker_id = CASE WHEN :broker_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN :broker_id ELSE broker_id END
                  AND transaction_time >= CASE WHEN :from_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END
                  AND transaction_time <= CASE WHEN :to_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:to_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END""", 
                  share_id = int(share_id_val), 
                  broker_id = int(broker_id_val),
                  from_date = from_date_val, 
                  to_date = to_date_val)
```

Or using `TO_NUMBER` in the SQL statement:

```py
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM trades WHERE 1=1
                  AND share_id = CASE WHEN :share_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN TO_NUMBER(:share_id) ELSE share_id END
                  AND broker_id = CASE WHEN :broker_id IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN TO_NUMBER(:broker_id) ELSE broker_id END
                  AND transaction_time >= CASE WHEN :from_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END
                  AND transaction_time <= CASE WHEN :to_date IS NOT NULL
                  THEN TO_DATE(:to_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                  ELSE transaction_time END""", 
                  share_id = share_id_val, 
                  broker_id = broker_id_val,
                  from_date = from_date_val, 
                  to_date = to_date_val)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked perfectly.